# Need help understanding the use of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality involving integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, integral-inequality

Let $\mathbf{f}:A\to\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $\mathbf{u}:B\to\mathbb{R}^{d}$ be two vector functions with coordinate functions $f_{j}$ and $u_{j}$, respectively. Then from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, it follows that:
\begin{equation}
\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\langle \mathbf{u}(t),\mathbf{f}(s)\rangle\,\mathrm{d}s\leq\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\lVert\mathbf{u}(t)\rVert\lVert\mathbf{f}(s)\rVert\,\mathrm{d}s, \tag 1
\end{equation}
where $t_{1}=\min\{t_{0},t\}$ and $t_{2}=\max\{t_{0},t\}$. Hence:
\begin{equation}
\left\lVert\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\mathbf{f}(s)\,\mathrm{d}s\right\rVert\leq\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\lVert\mathbf{f}(s)\rVert\,\mathrm{d}s. \tag 2
\end{equation}

**My question**: Why is it that the integral must have limits $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ after using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality? And how does $(2)$ follow from $(1)$? Thanks in advance! Please let me know if there's something that does not make sense.

**My thoughts**: In order to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in $(1)$ we need absolute values around the inner product in the integral such that:
\begin{equation}
\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\langle \mathbf{u}(t),\mathbf{f}(s)\rangle\,\mathrm{d}s=\int_{t_{0}}^{t} \lvert\langle \mathbf{u}(t),\mathbf{f}(s)\rangle\rvert\,\mathrm{d}s.
\end{equation}
However, might it be that the equality above is only true when $t_{0}<t$? If that is the case, then it would make sense why one defines $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ as above, right?

Comment: Is this the inner product on $\mathbb{R}^d$? In which case the inner product should be on $f$ and $u$ instead of their components?

Comment: @AndrewShedlock Thanks pointing that out! It has been fixed now. Sorry for any misunderstanding that it might've caused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first instance, we may have $t < t_0$.  Therefore, beginning with the inner product on the left of $(1)$,
\begin{align}
\int_{t_0}^t \langle \mathbf u(t), \mathbf f(s) \rangle ~ ds 
&\leqslant \left\lvert \int_{t_0}^t \langle \mathbf u(t), \mathbf f(s) \rangle ~ ds\right\rvert \\
&\leqslant \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left\lvert  \langle \mathbf u(t), \mathbf f(s) \rangle \right\rvert~ ds. \\
\end{align}
In moving the modulus sign inside the integral we need the limits of integration to be positively oriented, hence the need to make the change so that $t_1 \leqslant t_2$.  We can now apply Cauchy-Schwarz to the integrand,
\begin{align}
\int_{t_0}^t \langle \mathbf u(t), \mathbf f(s) \rangle ~ ds 
&\leqslant \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \lVert \mathbf u(t) \rVert ~\lVert \mathbf f(s) \rVert ~ ds.
\end{align}
Thus $(1)$ is obtained.

For $(2)$ take $\mathbf u(t)$ to be the unit vector defined by,
$$ \mathbf u(t) = \frac{\int_{t_0}^t \mathbf f(x)~dx}{\lVert \int_{t_0}^t \mathbf f(x) ~dx \rVert}$$
and substitute it into $(1)$.  The left hand side is seen to be simply
\begin{align} \left \lVert \int_{t_0}^t \mathbf f(s)~ds \right \rVert
\end{align}
while the right side, because $\lVert \mathbf u \rVert = 1$, becomes,
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \lVert f(s) \rVert ~ ds, $$ and the required result follows.

Comment: But why is it that when moving the absolute value sign inside the integral, we need the limits to be positively oriented??

Comment: Otherwise the integral would generate a negative value, but we need to have a positive value.  When the absolute value sign is outside the integral the orientation of $t$ and t_0$ does not matter.  When moving it inside, we need to arrange them positively for the statement to work.  Is that better?